# Crop an image using "pinch and zoom"

Tags: cordova, ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic3

I am looking for a way to allow users to crop an image using "pinch and zoom" when they take a picture on their camera or fetch an image from the phone's gallery. Any ideas how to achieve this in Ionic2?

Comment: Writing code would be a good start. We are not here to do that for you. YOU write some code, we (maybe) try help fix it.

Comment: I can write code up to the point of accessing an image from the phone gallery or taking a photo using Ionic2. I am asking for help on how to go about cropping the image using pinch and zoom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look at this [cordova plugin](https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-crop).

Like you can see in the `readme.md`, internally it uses:

- in iOS: `PEPhotoCropEditor` [link](https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop)
- in Android: `android-crop` [link](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/PEPhotoCropEditor)

By taking a look at those two links, you can see how they work and if it's that what you are looking for.